# Moving objects of a list to another list

Tags: r, list, for-loop, data.table, r-mice

I have lists of `mids` objects which are created by the `mice` library, which look as follows:

```
library(data.table)
library(mice)    
df <- fread(
    "A   B  C  D  E  F  iso   year   
     0   A   NA  1  NA  NA  NLD   2009   
     1   Y   NA  2  NA  NA  NLD   2009   
     0   Q   NA  3  NA  NA  AUS   2011   
     1   NA  NA  4  NA  NA  AUS   2011   
     0   0   NA  7  NA  NA  NLD   2008   
     1   1   NA  1  NA  NA  NLD   2008   
     0   1   NA  3  NA  NA  AUS   2012   
     0   NA  1   NA  1  NA  ECU   2009   
     1   NA  0   NA  2  0   ECU   2009   
     0   NA  0   NA  3  0   BRA   2011   
     1   NA  0   NA  4  0   BRA   2011   
     0   NA  1   NA  7  NA  ECU   2008   
     1   NA  0   NA  1  0   ECU   2008   
     0   NA  0   NA  3  2   BRA   2012   
     1   NA  0   NA  4  NA  BRA   2012",
   header = TRUE
)

# 1. Split df into smaller df
df_iso <- split(df, df$iso) # Creates a list of dataframes

# 2. Impute smaller df, creates a list with mids
df_iso_1 = list()
for (i in 1:length(df_iso))  {
  tryCatch({
    df_iso_1 [[i]] <- mice(df_iso[[i]], m=1, maxit = 5, seed=1)
    if (i==1000) stop("stop")
  }, error=function(e){cat("ERROR :",conditionMessage(e), "\n")})
}

df_iso_2 = list()
for (i in 1:length(df_iso))  {
  tryCatch({
    df_iso_2 [[i]] <- mice(df_iso[[i]], m=1, maxit = 5, seed=2)
    if (i==1000) stop("stop")
  }, error=function(e){cat("ERROR :",conditionMessage(e), "\n")})
}
```

I want to simply be able to move the `mids` objects of the lists `df_iso_1` and `df_iso_2` to another list, which has the name of the `ISO` code (which results in a list of `mids` objects with the same iso code instead of lists with all the iso codes). I have tried the following:

```
NLD = list()
AUS = list()
ECU = list()
BRA = list()

for (n in 1:length(df_iso_1)){
  if (df_iso_1[[i]]["data"]==NLD) {
  NLD[[i]] <- 
    df_iso_1[[i]] }
}
```

This however gives the error:

```
Error in Ops.data.frame(df_iso_1[[i]], NLD) : 
  list of length 21 not meaningful
```

Any suggestions of how to do this properly?

EDIT: Using Cole's answer, I think I would like to achieve the following:

```
names(df_iso_1) <- names(df_iso)
names(df_iso_2) <- names(df_iso)
for (n in 1:2) {
  x <- get(paste0("df_iso_", n))
  NLD[[n]] <- x[['NLD']]
}
```

This for some reason however only adds one item to the list NLD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
names(df_iso_1) <- names(df_iso)
NLD[[1]] <- df_iso_1[['NLD']]
```

We need to overcome that `df_iso_1` does not have any names to subset by. An alternative approach is to nest `lapply` statements and loop through `df_iso` and any seeds we want.

```
seeds = c(1,2)
df_iso_all <- lapply(df_iso,
                     function(ISO) lapply(seeds,
                                          function(seed) mice(ISO, m=1, maxit = 5, seed = seed)
                                          )
                     )

df_iso_all[['NLD']]
```

We can also include the `split` and the `lapply` in one line using the `by()` function.

```
#or split using by an do it at once:
by(data = df, INDICES = df$iso,
   FUN = function(ISO) lapply(seeds, function(seed) mice(ISO, m = 1, maxit = 5, seed = seed)))
```

You can even include some of the error handling with data processing ahead of time to only have 1,000 `iso`s.

```
df[, GRPING := .GRP, by = iso]
by(data = df[GRPING < 1000, !c('GRPING')],
   ...,
   ...)
```

Here's a copy and paste of the code that works on my computer:

```
library(data.table)
library(mice)    
df <- fread(
  "A   B  C  D  E  F  iso   year   
  0   A   NA  1  NA  NA  NLD   2009   
  1   Y   NA  2  NA  NA  NLD   2009   
  0   Q   NA  3  NA  NA  AUS   2011   
  1   NA  NA  4  NA  NA  AUS   2011   
  0   0   NA  7  NA  NA  NLD   2008   
  1   1   NA  1  NA  NA  NLD   2008   
  0   1   NA  3  NA  NA  AUS   2012   
  0   NA  1   NA  1  NA  ECU   2009   
  1   NA  0   NA  2  0   ECU   2009   
  0   NA  0   NA  3  0   BRA   2011   
  1   NA  0   NA  4  0   BRA   2011   
  0   NA  1   NA  7  NA  ECU   2008   
  1   NA  0   NA  1  0   ECU   2008   
  0   NA  0   NA  3  2   BRA   2012   
  1   NA  0   NA  4  NA  BRA   2012",
   header = TRUE
)

# 1. Split df into smaller df
df_iso <- split(df, df$iso) # Creates a list of dataframes

# 2. Impute smaller df, creates a list with mids
df_iso_1 = list()
for (i in 1:length(df_iso))  {
  tryCatch({
    df_iso_1 [[i]] <- mice(df_iso[[i]], m=1, maxit = 5, seed=1)
    if (i==1000) stop("stop")
  }, error=function(e){cat("ERROR :",conditionMessage(e), "\n")})
}

df_iso_2 = list()
for (i in 1:length(df_iso))  {
  tryCatch({
    df_iso_2 [[i]] <- mice(df_iso[[i]], m=1, maxit = 5, seed=2)
    if (i==1000) stop("stop")
  }, error=function(e){cat("ERROR :",conditionMessage(e), "\n")})
}

NLD = list()
AUS = list()
ECU = list()
BRA = list()

names(df_iso_1) <- names(df_iso)
names(df_iso_2) <- names(df_iso)

for (n in 1:2) {
  x <- get(paste0("df_iso_", n))
  NLD[[n]] <- x[['NLD']]
  AUS[[n]] <- x[['AUS']]
  ECU[[n]] <- x[['ECU']]
  BRA[[n]] <- x[['BRA']]
}

NLD
AUS
ECU
BRA
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! This is a huge help. Is there anyway to move the result up 1 level? The result now is that under [[1]], there is [NLD], but I need the [NLD] level to disappear and the info to be directly under [[1]]. Is that possible? Is there by the way any way to do this with a for-loop?

Comment: See edits. The change is just double bracket: ```df_iso_all[['NLD']]```. Out of curiosity, why do you prefer to have all of your objects saved separately instead of just one list?

Comment: Thank you very much Cole! I'm almost there, I just somehow cannot get the for-loop right (see edit). I initially arranged it like this to save memory while doing imputations. Now I have to put it back into this structure to make `mice` able to pool the imputations. I think in hindsight there were better options..

Comment: @Tom, your code worked for me. I copied and pasted all of my code. Each ```iso``` is a list of 2.

Comment: When I copied your code it somehow worked for me too.. Perhaps I overlooked in error in my own code. In any case thank you very much for all your help!